# Unable to Pass data to view by controller after switching to mobile view Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using a plugin Class to switch Layout from web to mobile by adding suffix .mobile to each file . I am facing a problem of passing any data to that view i am loading

**Here is my plugin**

```
class Ag_Controller_Plugin_DeviceLayout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

   public function postDispatch(\Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
      $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
      if (preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i', $useragent) || preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i', substr($useragent, 0, 4)))
         $device_type = 'mobile';
      else
         $device_type = 'desktop';
      if ($device_type == "mobile" && !$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
         Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout("mobile_layout");
         $base = APPLICATION_PATH . "/views/scripts/";
         $mobile = $base . $request->getControllerName() . "/" . $request->getActionName() . ".mobile.phtml";
         if (is_readable($mobile)) {
            Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('ViewRenderer')->setViewSuffix('mobile.phtml');
         }
      }
   }

}
```

**Here is my controller .**

```
public function indexAction(){
            $obj= Ag_Manufacturer::getInstance();


            $where=array();
            $where[Ag_Constant::RECYCLE_COLUMN_NAME.'=?']='1';
            $manufaturers=$obj->getAll($where);

           //$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
            $this->view->manufaturers=$manufaturers;
        }
```

In my **desktop** view i am getting this variable  by

```
$this->manufaturers
```

But in my `mobile` view getting NULL.

I have kind of solve the problem but i dont think its a better solution 
**here is my mobile_layout.phtml file**

```
<?php 
$params=array();
$params['request']=$this->request;
$params['currentUser']=$this->currentUser;
$params['userHelper']=$this->userHelper;
$params['data']=$this->data;
?>
       <!-- Header-->
       <?php echo $this->partial('templates/header.mobile.phtml',$params);?>
      <?php
      $mobile     =   $this->request->getControllerName() . "/" . $this->request->getActionName() . ".mobile.phtml";
      echo $this->partial($mobile,$params);




        <!-- ..........footer............ -->            
        <?php echo $this->partial('templates/footer.mobile.phtml',$params);?>
```

And here is web  layout.phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->partial('templates/header.phtml',$params);?>
<!-- Content Starts -->
<!-- Content Starts -->
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>

<?php $data=NULL; ?>
<!-- Contents End -->
<!-- Contents End -->

<?php //echo $this->partial('templates/bottom-reviews.php'); ?>

<?php echo $this->partial('templates/footer.phtml'); ?>

<?php //echo $this->partial('templates/footer-scripts.php'); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->partial('templates/web-tracking.phtml',$params);?>
```

**In MY both views** 
I am using this line of code for both to access

```
print_r($this->manufaturers);
```

Comment: Can you add both mobile and desktop view code, to the question please.

Comment: I got clue from my mobile layout file though i.e i am adding ...to the question

Answer (score 0):

I have how ever resolved it by 
adding this line of code to my mobile_layout.phtml

```
$params['data']=$this->data;
```

and then in my Controller Index Action doing this

```
public function indexAction(){
            $obj= Ag_Manufacturer::getInstance();


            $where=array();
            $where[Ag_Constant::RECYCLE_COLUMN_NAME.'=?']='1';
            $manufaturers=$obj->getAll($where);



            $this->view->manufaturers=$manufaturers;
            //incase for mobile
            $this->view->data=$manufaturers;
        }
```